# Python unittest - multiple assertions => don't fail if at least of one them passes

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm doing that at the moment:

```
try:
    self.assertIsNotNone(a)
except AssertionError:
    try:
        self.assertIsTrue(b)
    except AssertionError:
        try:
            self.assertIn(c, C)
        except AssertionError:
            self.assertIsInstance(d, D)
```

(any of these assertions should pass)

How to do that better?

--

**UPDATE:** use any kind of assertion

Comment: You could do `e = a or b or c or d` and then `self.assertIsNotNone(e)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
self.assertFalse(any(x is None for x in (a, b, c, d)))
```